# Blank Page and No Download PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Can anyone help me with PHPExcel?

I have this code...

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnect.php';
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partner1 WHERE uid=" . $_GET['id']);
while ($userRow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:A27")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:A27")->getFont()->setSize(16);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('2')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('3')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('4')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('5')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('6')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('7')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('8')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('9')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('10')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('11')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('12')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('13')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('14')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('15')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('16')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('17')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('18')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('19')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('20')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('21')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('22')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('23')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('24')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('25')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('26')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('27')->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);


// Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Test 123")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("-")
        ->setTitle("" . $userRow1['nome'] . " " . $userRow1['cognome'] . "")
        ->setSubject("-")
        ->setDescription("-")
        ->setKeywords("-")
        ->setCategory("-");


// Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Codice Op')
        ->setCellValue('A2', 'DATA:')
        ->setCellValue('A3', 'DATI CLIENTE')
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'Nome')
        ->setCellValue('A5', 'Cognome')
        ->setCellValue('A6', 'Data e Luogo di nascita')
        ->setCellValue('A7', 'Via')
        ->setCellValue('A8', 'Cumune,Cap,PR')
        ->setCellValue('A9', 'Telefono rete fissa')
        ->setCellValue('A10', 'Recapito Alternativo')
        ->setCellValue('A11', 'Tipo Documento')
        ->setCellValue('A12', 'Ente di rilascio')
        ->setCellValue('A13', 'Data Rilascio')
        ->setCellValue('A14', 'Data Scadenza')
        ->setCellValue('A15', 'Codice Fiscale')
        ->setCellValue('A16', 'PROPOSTA')
        ->setCellValue('A17', 'OFFERTA')
        ->setCellValue('A18', 'TIM VISION')
        ->setCellValue('A19', 'Modem (s/n)')
        ->setCellValue('A20', 'Gestore telefonico')
        ->setCellValue('A21', 'Codice di migrazione1')
        ->setCellValue('A22', 'Codice di migrazione2')
        ->setCellValue('A23', 'ICCID')
        ->setCellValue('A24', 'Numero per Smart')
        ->setCellValue('A25', 'Gestore Mobile')
        ->setCellValue('A26', 'Inserimento Elenco Telefonico')
        ->setCellValue('A27', 'NATIVO TELECOM')
        ->setCellValue('B1', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B2', '' . $userRow1['data'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B3', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B4', '' . $userRow1['nome'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B5', '' . $userRow1['cognome'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B6', '' . $userRow1['natoil'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B7', '' . $userRow1['via'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B8', '' . $userRow1['cumune'] . ' , ' . $userRow1['cap'] . ' , ' . $userRow1['provincia'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B9', '' . $userRow1['numero'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B10', '' . $userRow1['ricapitodicell'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B11', '' . $userRow1['documento'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B12', '' . $userRow1['rilascio'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B13', '' . $userRow1['scadenza'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B14', '' . $userRow1['codicefiscale'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B15', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B16', '' . $userRow1['ofertascelta'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B17', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B18', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B19', '' . $userRow1['operatoretelefonico'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B20', '' . $userRow1['codicemigrazione'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B21', '' . $userRow1['iccid'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B22', '' . $userRow1['celloftsm'] . '')
        ->setCellValue('B23', ' ')
        ->setCellValue('B24', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B25', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B26', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B27', '-');

// Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}

exit;
```

When I try to read and download my database data to excel format I get a blank page and no download.

I don't get any error on this. I don't know what to do lol

Comment: typically when you end up with a blank page, it's because you have an error in your code and error reporting is turned off.

Comment: Error reporting is TRUE mate , im watching for every refresh my error_log

Comment: One thing i notice is you have your while statement closed at the very end of your page, but you include the header inside that. That means you're sending your header multiple times. Another thing I would recommend would be to use a for loop on these lines `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);`. All you're doing is incrementing from 1-27, so you can simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious problems (just wading through this wall of code)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

will still continue executing the rest of the code

You're including PHPExcel, creating a new PHPExcel object, and sending the response to the browser for every single row that you iterate in the while `$userRow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))` loop.... I'm assuming that you really want each row to be written to the same file

**EDIT**

Trying to keep the answer simple, rather than a wall of code, your structure should be something like:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partner1 WHERE uid=".$_GET['id']);

while($userRow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Codice Op')
            .....
    ;
}

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Also note that the mysql extension is deprecated in PHP, you should really be using mysqli or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables to protect your script against SQL injection

Comment: can you please help me by making the necessary changes to the code?

Comment: Now Downloaded but BLANK xls File :(

Comment: Well perhaps your SQL query isn't returning any records